I am getting an error "Bad CPU type in executable" on line 44 in node when installing CLI on my MacBook Pro 2018
SFDX Error in macOs:
/usr/local/bin/sfdx: line 44: /usr/local/lib/sfdx/bin/node: Bad CPU type in executable
when I try the SFDX: Authorize an Org command.I'm on a MACOS, macbook pro-2018.
sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias vscodeOrg --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername.

This could be more readable if you use back-ticks to delimit the error message and the command. Right now, it's difficult to see when the computer model ends and the command starts. Judging from problems in 2021 and 2022, installing Rosetta by running softwareupdate is a good thing to try. If that fails, edit the question to include the Rosetta version and full CPU details.
